# Current decay in RL circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I guess this has been asked before many a times. But I searched for it and couldn't find the question. Any kind of qualitative answer will be really helpful.

When a magnetically charged inductor is connected in series with a resistor, it is known that the current decays exponentially through the resistor and becomes zero after a long time.

This is also mathematically supported by the equation, $i(t)=I_{o}e^{\frac {-tR}{L}}$. My question is how can current decrease to zero ? How can charges flowing in the circuit decrease to zero ?

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Heat energy**

If your question is ‘where’ the current (essentially the EMF) stored in the inductor goes, it would be lost as heat energy when the current passes through the resistor.

Since current requires the electron to move, when they lose their kinetic energy as heat, the current becomes zero.

Comment: Can electrons come to rest in a closed circuit ?

Comment: @User12121 when we talk about current, we mean *net* flow of electrons. When a potential difference is applied across a conductor, there is *net* flow from the higher potential to the lower potential. Electrons aren’t necessarily as rest when there is no current, they posses thermal kinetic energy. However, this motion is random and the net result being the electrons ‘cancel’ each others motion on a large scale, meaning no *net* movement of electrons meaning no current.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can current decrease to zero ? How can charges
> flowing in the circuit decrease to zero ?

The current decreases to zero because all the energy initially stored in the magnetic field of the inductor is dissipated as heat in the resistor. The charges in the circuit don't decrease to zero, they simply stop moving in the form of current.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm !!! I had a kind of strange notion that electrons' motion can/will never be stopped in a  closed circuit, because they are continuously moving in a conductor.

Comment: @User12121  I specifically included the statement "in the form of current" to distinguish between motion stopping entirely (which is never the case since there is always random thermal movement) vs the collective movement of electrons. Is that clear to you now?

Comment: Yupp thanks a lot ! In general, the behavior of electrons is always intriguing and it's hard to imagine or visualize. Or there is always quantum mechanics for precise understanding and that's an ocean again.

Comment: @User12121 Yeah, but in this case a classical understanding is sufficient

Comment: @User12121 Also useful to note that the "drift velocity" of the electrons, generating current is *far* lower than the speed that electronic signals propagate at (some high fraction of the speed of light).  That's a very unintuitive thing which can be useful to hold onto